# timeGetTime - кто управляет им?

Tags: winapi, vba, vb6

`Private Declare Function timeGetTime Lib "winmm.dll" () As Long`

[BG says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

И все бы ничего, но... 
... дьявол кроется в мелочах as:
[timeBeginPeriod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and
[timeEndPeriod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Просьба к тем, кто знает эти нюансы не глазами, но руками, скажите, плз, прав ли я, отказываясь от регулярного каждый рабочий буржуйский день) и долговременного (21 час из 24) использования этого таймера по причине того, что:

любая программа в любой момент изменить значение его разрешения, что повлияет на мою, уже исполняющуюся программу?

Сейчас (несколько лет уже) я успешно пользую [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
.

---

**Add:**

> Remarks on timeBeginPeriod
>
> Call this function **immediately before** using timer services, and **call
>   the timeEndPeriod function immediately after** you are finished using
>   the timer services.
>
> You must match each call to timeBeginPeriod with a call to
>   timeEndPeriod, specifying the same minimum resolution in both calls.
>   An application can make multiple timeBeginPeriod calls as long as each
>   call is matched with a call to timeEndPeriod.
>
> **This function affects a global Windows** setting. **Windows uses the
>   lowest value** (that is, highest resolution) **requested by any process**.
>   Setting a **higher resolution can improve the accuracy** of time-out
>   intervals in wait functions. However, it can **also reduce overall
>   system performance**, because the thread scheduler switches tasks more
>   often. High resolutions can also prevent the CPU power management
>   system from entering power-saving modes. Setting a **higher resolution
>   does not improve the accuracy** of the high-resolution performance
>   counter.

Comment: *любая программа в любой момент изменить значение его разрешения, что повлияет на мою, уже исполняющуюся программу?* С какого это перепугу? Была у тебя точность в 5мс (или больше - но это зависит только от машины). И какой у тебя появится головняк, если ошибка понизится?

Comment: @Akina Да ни с какого. Просто ей так захочется - повысить точность до 1 msc, отобрать через это ресурсы и приоритеты. Карл ведь в своем проекте ccrp timer не случайно предупреждает о необоснованном завышении разрешения и возможном влиянии на другие проги.

Comment: @Akina Или понизить до 50. Или до 150. Или до 15000.

Comment: *Или понизить* Не бывает.

Comment: @Akina "Или понизить Не бывает" - т.е. разрешение может лишь повышаться, по твоим словам. А обратно, назад - никак?

Comment: *А обратно, назад - никак?* Только в пределах ошибки. У тебя есть функция, которая возвращает тебе некие абстрактные тики. Она всего лишь сообщает тебе некое состояние какого-то внутреннего счётчика. Этот счётчик обновляется гораздо чаще - но именно поллинг порождает среднюю ошибку в 5 мс. Изменение скорости обновления этого счётчика никак не влияет на точность получения данных поллингом - ведь на процесс счёта ты никаким образом не влияешь.

Comment: @Akina Стоп. Карл дает возможность установить своему таймеру требуемой разрешение, вплоть до макисмально доступного (у меня - 1 мск). Если работают какие-то проги с консервативным 20 мск, а я заряжаю 1 мск - это как? Ничо? Или, наоборот. Я ставлю 1000 - и те, кто его юзают получают по сусалам, расчитывая на 20. Не так?

Comment: @Akina я не борюсь за точность. Я борюсь за достоверность... Пусть плохонько, но надежно.

Comment: Повторяю - точность пересчёта этого значения может быть только увеличена. Грубо: если ты поставишь таймер на 100 мс - это значит, что он так и будет обновляться раз в 5 мс. Но если ты затребуешь точность в 2 мс, то его значение начнёт обновляться один раз в 1 мс. Или 1 раз в 2 мс. В любом случае, точность хуже, чем была, не станет. А вот остальные процессы могут начать тормозить, потому что процедура обновления счётчика начнёт выполняться не 200 раз в секунду, а 500 или 1000...

Comment: @Akina Я не могу понять (ты второй раз утверждаешь) **"точность ... может быть только увеличена"**. И снова спошу - а назад - никак? Бзв, я добавил пост цитатой от БГ. Он то, как раз и требует - верните назад по возможности скорее, как только перестанет нужна высокая точность. Вот эти изменения, которые может вносить ЛЮБОЙ процесс, меня и тревожат.

Comment: Ещё раз. Есть счётчик. Есть некий управляемый только ОС процесс, который его меняет. И есть показанные тобой функции, которые его читают. Пока ты ничего не трогаешь, процесс считает с точностью ~5мс, т.е раз в 5мс обновляет значение, прибавляя по 5 в каждом обновлении. Если ты через функции затребовал более высокую точность, он начнёт обновлять счётчик чаще, скажем, каждые 1 мс прибавляя по 1. Ну или каждые 2мс прибавляя по 2. Но и в том, и в другом случае за 1 секунду (1000 мс) значение счётчика будет увеличено на 1000.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за участие в обсуждении. Я еще раз внимательно перечитаю все, понаписанное тобой и мной, и чуть позже вернусь к этому вопросу. Он актуален для меня. Но в данный момент я переключился на другой проект.